# Best practices in building ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net

We are building an ASP.NET application (with C#.net as language) and will be hosting on Windows Server 2003 Operating System with SQL Server 2008 as database.

We are planning to implement the best practices in writing code, dividing the application into logical blocks, services etc.

Would you please guide me on this, if you have an idea?

If would be great if you could also provide a reference document or web references (If needed).

Many Thanks,

Regards,
Venkat.

Comment: what kind of site will this be? A online shop, a website with loads of content where people can search, comment, send to a friend etc.., a application used by a small group of office employees faciliting a specific business process?

Answer (score 6):

This isn't what you want to hear, but your best bet might be to bring on a senior asp.net guy who has a lot of experience and put him in  charge of this.

But that's an extremely broad question, Venkat. Maybe if you could narrow it down a  bit more we could provide a more useful answer.

I would perhaps recommend one book called Framework Design Guidelines, which is published by Microsoft Press. It goes into a lot of best practices on writing code, naming conventions, how to design classes, etc. And there are dialogues in there between Microsoft's top language guys. Sometimes they disagree, and that's always interesting.

But that's just one piece of the puzzle. I could talk for hours about methodologies, architectural patterns, object oriented theory, seperation of concerns, etc. As stated, your question covers all that ground.